# How to prevent wire-elements modal to clear my properties on the other component?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I have 3 components:

1. `Input` and `The total` components

   [image]

   here is the code of the first component:

   ```php
   class SearchBarang extends Component
   {
       public $totalAll;

       public function createOrUpdate()
       {
           $checkBarangDalamList = TransaksiJualDetail::where('transaksi_jual_id', $this->transaksiJual)
               ->where('barang_id', $this->barang->id)
               ->first();

           if ($checkBarangDalamList == null) {
               $this->addNewStuff();
               $this->addTotal();
               $this->reset('barcode');
               $this->emit('storeNewList', $this->transaksiJual);
           } else {
               $this->addQuantity();
               $this->addTotal();
               $this->reset('barcode');
               $this->emit('storeNewList', $this->transaksiJual);
           }
       }

       public function addTotal()
       {
           $total = TransaksiJualDetail::all()
               ->where('transaksi_jual_id', $this->transaksiJual);

           $this->totalAll = $total->sum('total');
       }
   ```
2. The `Table` component
3. The `Modal` component

   [image]

The problem is, when I close the modal, my `$totalAll` property which is Rp. 4.706.095 will reset. So, how can I prevent that?

[image]

the property of total default value is 0 and not stored to the database

here is my code to close the modal:

```php
class EditBarang extends ModalComponent
{
    public TransaksiJualDetail $transaksiJualDetail;

    public $quantity;

    public $harga;

    public $discount_persen;

    public $discount_value;

    public $subtotal;

    public $total;
    
    public $keterangan;

    public function mount(TransaksiJualDetail $transaksiJualDetail)
    {
        $this->quantity = $transaksiJualDetail->qty;
        $this->harga = $transaksiJualDetail->harga;
        $this->discount_persen = $transaksiJualDetail->discount_persen;
        $this->discount_value = $transaksiJualDetail->discount_value;
        $this->subtotal = $transaksiJualDetail->subtotal;
        $this->total = $transaksiJualDetail->total;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.kasir.edit-barang');
    }
}
```

Here is the close button:

```
<button wire:click="$emit('closeModal')" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-sm hover:opacity-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-red-500 text-white">Batal</button>
```

Comment: If you do not share any code at all, it is impossible to help you

Comment: updated, can you please check my code ?